# What is the proper way to achieve inter object communication in android?

Tags: java, android, communication

I have the following problem on Android:

My MainActivity has an instance of a Class named ObjA. ObjA detects a user input and needs to notify MainActivity by sending three pieces of information: a string, an int and a float. This data will be private variables of an object (ObjB). The only way I know to pass object to the MainActivity is to pass a copy of MainActivity to ObjA and have ObjA call on a function of MainActivity. Is there another way to do this?